# Merging two Magento 2 installations

Tags: magento, magento2

I had two different Magento stores running on Magento 1.9 each on a separate installation. I have upgraded one to Magento 2 which is running fine. Is it possible to now upload/convert the old website (still on Magento 1.9) to this new Magento 2 installation as a separate store.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that this is possible to upload/convert in a simple way. If there are a lot of data (categories, products, cms blocks and pages, customers) you could try to use official [migration tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-tool-install.html) or write a custom scripts by yourself.

Comment: I am aware of the platform differences between the two Magento versions as have already migrated one of the stores to Magento 2. I can do the same for the other store as well. In that case I will have two separate Magento installations. Is there any possibility or tool that can merge my two updated websites as separate stores on the same Magento installation

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 is completely different to Magento 1, it is a complete rebuild of the platform; unfortunately there is no quick and easy way to convert your old M1 site to M2. There are 3 essential areas to cover:

1. Template
2. Functionality
3. Data

Your templates will need to be rebuilt as well as any custom or 3rd party modules, however there are a fair few extensions out there you can leverage. Finally, and the most volatile, is your data, I suggest using the official [migration tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-tool-install.html) or use a data transfer service such as [Cart 2 Cart](https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/migration-by-version/upgrade-magento-1-9-to-2-1) to migrate the data from M1 to M2.

Comment: I am aware of the platform differences between the two Magento versions as have already migrated one of the stores to Magento 2. I can do the same for the other store as well. In that case I will have two separate Magento installations. Is there any possibility or tool that can merge my two updated websites as separate stores on the same Magento installation.